# Keras model output information/log level

Tags: python-3.x, keras

I am using Keras to build a neural network model:

```
model_keras = Sequential()
model_keras.add(Dense(4, input_dim=input_num, activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)))
model_keras.add(Dense(1, activation='linear',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)))
sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, clipnorm=0.5)
model_keras.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',  optimizer=sgd)
model_keras.fit(X_norm_train, y_norm_train, batch_size=20, epochs=100)
```

The output looks like below. I am wondering if it is possible to out the loss, say every 10 epochs instead of every epoch? Thanks!

```
Epoch 1/200
20/20 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.2661
Epoch 2/200
20/20 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.2625
Epoch 3/200
20/20 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.2590
Epoch 4/200
20/20 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.2556
Epoch 5/200
20/20 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.2523
Epoch 6/200
20/20 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.2490
Epoch 7/200
20/20 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.2458
Epoch 8/200
20/20 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.2427
Epoch 9/200
20/20 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.2397
Epoch 10/200
20/20 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.2367
Epoch 11/200
20/20 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.2338
Epoch 12/200
20/20 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.2309
Epoch 13/200
20/20 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.2281
Epoch 14/200
20/20 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.2254
Epoch 15/200
20/20 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.2228
   :
```

Answer (score 9):

It is not possible to reduce frequency of logging to stdout, however, passing `verbose=0` argument to `fit()` method would turn logging completely off.

Since the loop over epochs is not exposed in the Keras' sequential model, one way to collect scalar variable summaries with a custom frequency would be using Keras [callbacks](https://keras.io/callbacks/). In particular, you could use `TensorBoard` (assuming you are running with `tensorflow` backend) or `CSVLogger` (any backend) callbacks to collect any scalar variable summaries (training loss, in your case):

```
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard

model_keras = Sequential()
model_keras.add(Dense(4, input_dim=input_num, activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)))
model_keras.add(Dense(1, activation='linear',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)))
sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, clipnorm=0.5)
model_keras.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',  optimizer=sgd)

TB = TensorBoard(histogram_freq=10, batch_size=20)

model_keras.fit(X_norm_train, y_norm_train, batch_size=20, epochs=100, callbacks=[TB])
```

Setting `histogram_freq=10` will save loss every 10 epochs.

EDIT: passing `validation_data=(...)` to the `fit` method will also allow to check validation level metrics.

Comment: I tried the TensorBoard with histogram_freq=10, but it still print the loss for every epoch ... any parameter I might need to fix?

Comment: TensorBoard will not change frequency of what is printed on the screen, but it will produce a file with summaries (i.e. loss every 10 epochs), which can be viewed in a browser or accessed using `tensorboard.backend.event_processing.event_accumulator` in the script and then plotted.

Comment: @Edamame To stop printing the loss for every epoch, change your last line to `model_keras.fit(X_norm_train, y_norm_train, batch_size=20, epochs=100, verbose=0)`, with the only difference being the inclusion of `verbose=0`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Keras callback to reduce the number of log lines. By default, Keras print log per every epoch. The following code prints only 10 log lines regardless the number of epochs.

```
class callback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
  def on_epoch_end(this,Epoch,Logs):
    L = Logs["loss"];

    if Epoch%Lafte==Lafte-1: #Log after a number of epochs
      print(f"Average batch loss: {L:.9f}");
    if Epoch==Epochs-1:
      print(f"Fin-avg batch loss: {L:.9f}"); #Final average

Model = model();
Model.compile(...);

Dsize  = ...   #Number of samples in training data
Bsize  = ...   #Number of samples to process in 1 batch
Steps  = 1000; #Number of batches to use to train
Epochs = round(Steps/(Dsize/Bsize));
Lafte  = round(Epochs/10); #Log 10 times only, regardless of num of Epochs
if Lafte==0: Lafte=1;      #Avoid modulus by zero in on_epoch_end

Model.fit(Data, epochs=Epochs, steps_per_epoch=round(Dsize/Bsize),
          callbacks=[callback()], verbose=0);
```